# Need help understanding char array and stringlength

Tags: arrays, char, constants, string-length

```
void func(const char*s, char& c)
{
c = s [strlen(s) / 2];
cout << c;
}


void main()
{
char str[] = "ABCDE";
char ch = str[1];
func(str, ch);
}
```

Hello I need somone to explain to me whats going on in the void func()
I know what a constant is but what does char *s do?

and what  does s[strlen(s)/2] do I know that strlen returns the length of  astring however I don't know what s[ does out side of it.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C strings are null-terminated arrays of chars. `char*` is pointer to `char`, When pointer points to the first element of array - we can use
`s[n]` which takes element `n`(zero-based) of that array.

So in provided code 'middle' character is taken